# Enable Disable radio buttons based on models value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, radio-button

I am using Vue bootstrap, and I currently have several radio buttons.

```
<b-form-radio-group
    id="radio1"
    v-model="$v.form.radio1.$model"
    name="radio1"
  >
    <b-form-radio value="yes">
      Yes
    </b-form-radio>
    <b-form-radio value="no">
      No
    </b-form-radio>
</b-form-radio-group>

<b-form-radio-group
    :disabled="$v.form.radio1.$model !== 'yes'"
    id="radio2"
    v-model="$v.form.radio2.$model"
    name="radio2"
  >
    <b-form-radio value="yes">
      Yes
    </b-form-radio>
    <b-form-radio value="no">
      No
    </b-form-radio>
</b-form-radio-group>

<b-form-radio-group
    :disabled="$v.form.radio2.$model !== 'yes'"
    id="radio3"
    v-model="$v.form.radio3.$model"
    name="radio3"
    >
    <b-form-radio value="yes">
      Yes
    </b-form-radio>
    <b-form-radio value="no">
      No
    </b-form-radio>
</b-form-radio-group>
```

I want these radios to be answered in order, so I disable them until the previous radio button has an answer of yes.  To do this, I just check the vmodel value for the previous radio

```
:disabled="$v.form.radio1.$model !== 'yes'"
```

This seems to work, but I have a problem.  If I answer yes to all 3 radio buttons, and then revisit radio1 and change this to no, radio2 is disabled again as it should be.  However,
with this setup, radio3 is still enabled.  I basically need it so that if a radio is set to no, all following radio buttons should be disabled.  If it is set to yes, the next following
radio should be enabled.

How can I achieve something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a snippet utilizing the input event.
If the value gets changed to `no` it will change the next radio button you've defined to `no` as well, which will fire another input event and bubble through the order.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
          radio1: 'no',
          radio2: 'no',
          radio3: 'no'
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onChanged(nextRadio, newValue) {
        if(newValue === 'no'){
          this.form[nextRadio] = 'no'
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.4/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.4/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-radio-group
      id="radio1"
      v-model="form.radio1"
      name="radio1"
      @input="onChanged('radio2', $event)"
    >
      <b-form-radio value="yes">
        Yes
      </b-form-radio>
      <b-form-radio value="no">
        No
      </b-form-radio>
  </b-form-radio-group>

  <b-form-radio-group
      :disabled="form.radio1 !== 'yes'"
      id="radio2"
      v-model="form.radio2"
      name="radio2"
      @input="onChanged('radio3', $event)"
    >
      <b-form-radio value="yes">
        Yes
      </b-form-radio>
      <b-form-radio value="no">
        No
      </b-form-radio>
  </b-form-radio-group>

  <b-form-radio-group
      :disabled="form.radio2 !== 'yes'"
      id="radio3"
      v-model="form.radio3"
      name="radio3"
      >
      <b-form-radio value="yes">
        Yes
      </b-form-radio>
      <b-form-radio value="no">
        No
      </b-form-radio>
  </b-form-radio-group>
</div>
```